# building 3rd party toolbox MATLAB ( ComplexNetworksPackage.1.6.Mac64.zip )

Tags: matlab, social-networking, toolbox

I downloaded the toolbox from http://www.levmuchnik.net/Content/Networks/ComplexNetworksPackage.html

the latest version 64 bit for Mac computer. The instructions on the site report:

> Build the x32 or the 64-bit version depending on the version of MatLab you have and add the obtained binaries along with the corresponding m-files to the main Graph folder.

The problem is that I can't find any executable file. I simply don't know which file to execute, what to do.

I already searched around this forum and so on, but no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you downloaded the 64-bit MAC package with pre-build binaries (ComplexNetworksPackage.1.6.Mac64.zip), the binary executable files are included.  They are the files ending in the .mexmaci64.  Just unzip the file in to some directory, then either add that directory to your path (`addpath` or `pathtool`) or `cd` to that directory in MATLAB.  At that point you should be able to run the MEX functions by name (e.g. for mexGraphAllNodeNeighbours.mexmaci64, run `mexGraphAllNodeNeighbours` at the MATLAB command prompt).  Note that there are companion M-files with the same name as the MEX files that usually contain documentation, but occasionally contain a M file only implementation if a valid MEX-file is not available.  Anyway, to check that you have for example mexGraphAllNodeNeighbours on your path,

```
which -all mexGraphAllNodeNeighbours
```

If it doesn't list the MEX-file, check your path and verify that you have the right platform (MAC 64-bit **and** 64-bit MATLAB installed).

Alternatively, you can download the source (ComplexNetworksPackage.1.6.Sources.zip) and build the MEX-files, but I wouldn't advise you to do that unless you have no choice.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and answer to me. You solved my problem. I'll take my time to be more acquainted with this, have a nice day, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have to build the binaries, it means they provide you with the source code (probably in C), and you probably need to generate the corresponding `mex` files (akin to DLL on Windows), using a supported compiler. Contact the toolbox authors for more detailed information as to what files you need to compile this way and have a look at the documentation for [`mex`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) in MATLAB.

See [Supported and Compatible Compilers – Release 2013b](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/compilers/R2013b/index.html?sec=maci64) for supported compilers on Mac (older releases linked from that page).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! There are a lot of mex file, if you say that those are the outcome of binaries built still I am not able to use the functions in the folder ( if you take the time to download it, it is light and maybe it will be clearer than my exposition). i can't manage to get it working, trying to follow a tutorial for the package it simply say that it doesn' recognise the functions used. Again, thank you

Comment: @user2126730 See chappjc's answer